# Почему в первом console.log() Объект содержит будущее значение = "Y"

Tags: javascript, объекты

```js
    let arData = {
        DATA: {
            COMPLETED: 'N',
        }
    };
    console.log(arData);
    
    arData.DATA.COMPLETED = "Y";
    console.log(arData);
```

Comment: не содержит....

Comment: Прошу попробовать запустить в консоли браузера

Comment: я жму на кнопку "выполнить код" в вопросе и вижу результат

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Консоль *браузера* запоминает ссылку на объект и показывает текущее состояние этого объекта.

Консоль *фрагмента кода на SO* показывает строковое представление объекта в момент вызова `console.log`.

Если нужен второй вариант, используйте

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(arData));
```